# Add Text at the Beginning of each new Line EditText

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the text inout by the user in EditText,so I got the new text and detected the new line in it but I want to add a text at the begining of each new line..How to do that ?

```
Ibold.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher(){
                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged( CharSequence txt, int start, int before, int count ) {
                        if (-1 != bold.indexOf("\n") ){


                           //here I detected new line


                        }
                    }
```

Comment: what you want to add at the beginning of every line?

Comment: I want to add this: *                       just some text

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Ibold.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher(){
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged( CharSequence txt, int start, int before, int count ) {
                    if (-1 != bold.indexOf("\n") ){


                       //here I detected new line
                        String editTextContent = Ibold.getText().toString();
                        editTextContent += "ADD YOUR TEXT HERE, IT WILL BE INSERTED AFTER THE LAST LINE BREAK";
                        Ibold.setText(editTextContent);


                    }
                }
```

Reference: [Android - Edit Text](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)

Comment: The app is freezing,keybaord also

Comment: I want to add text directly at the begining of the new line